# Здравствуйте, мне нужно написать методы SingleList(pop_back(), add(), remove()) помогите разобраться с ними!

Tags: c++, linked-list

1. methods: `push_back(T element)`, `pop_back()`, `add(T element, int index)`,
   `set(T element, int index)`, `remove(int index)`
2. operators: `==`, `!=`, `>>`, `<<`
   такое дело я начал с `push_back(T element)`, `pop_back()` и вроде уловил как делать дальше
   я начал писать метод Add но если честно я не совсем понимаю где использовать адрес или указатель в написал код смотря примеры помогите разобраться

```
class SingleList {
    class Node {
    public: 
        T data; 
        Node* next;

        Node(T data = T(), Node* next = nullptr) {
              this->data = data;
              this->next = next;
        }
    };

    int size;
    Node* head;

public:
    SingleList() {
        size = 0;
        head = nullptr;
    }
    int length() {
        return size;
    }

void add(T element, int index) {
    if(*Node==NULL) {
        *Node = new Node;
    } else {
        while (*Node->next!=NULL) {
            *Node = Node->next;
        }
        *Node->next= new Node;
    }
    ++size;
}
```

Comment: что то мой код слился

Comment: Что-то этот код один в один с тем, который только что закрыли .

Comment: ну я же не** прошу написать мне код

Comment: Зачем? Что бы вы ничего так и не поняли как это должно работать? В чем тогда смысл в обучении?

Comment: опечатка я так и хочу узнать как оно работает

Answer (score 0):

чисто по дизайну:

1. а зачем использовать `NULL`, когда есть родной `nullptr` и он уже в коде используется?
2. если методы только возвращают данные и не меняют их, то делать такие методы константными:

   ```
    int length() const {
        return size;
    }
   ```
3. используется шаблонный тип `T`, а где в коде вообще объявление `template`?
4. в классе `Node` есть конструктор с параметром и только, почему он не используется?

   ```
    if(*Node==NULL) {
        *Node = new Node;
    }
   ```

почему не делается так:

```
    if(head== nullptr) {
        head= new Node(element);
    }
```

5. если `Node` - это класс, то что делает

   ```
    *Node =
   ```

ошибки не смущают? как классу что-то можно присваивать?

А переменной вы тоже присваиваете значение так же:

```
float pi;
float = 3.14159;
```

?

в общем код с полным непониманием базовых вещей :(

может сначала все таки попробовать основы C++ подучить?

начните для начала не с шаблонного класса - пусть это будет класс для работы c int

потом руками пропишите туда 2-3 элемента и определите метод `int get(const int indx) const`

и т.д. и идите от более простых методов работы к более сложным